# WCF contract mismatch problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have a client console app talking to a WCF service and I get the following error:
"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

I think it's because of a contract mismatch but i can't figure out why. The service runs just fine by itself and the 2 parts were working together until i added the impersonation code.

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Here is the client, all done in code:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.tcp://serverName:9990/TestService1"));
ChannelFactory<IService1> channel = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endPoint);
channel.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
IService1 service = channel.CreateChannel();
```

And here is the config file of the WCF service:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFTest.ConsoleHost2.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFTest.ConsoleHost2.Service1Behavior"
          name="WCFTest.ConsoleHost2.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFTest.ConsoleHost2.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
            contract="WCFTest.ConsoleHost2.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://serverName:9999/TestService1/" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://serverName:9990/TestService1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 33):

**Other possible causes:**

- Trying to serialize an object without a default constructor.
- Trying to serialize some other kind of non serializable object (such as an Exception). To prevent the item from being serialized apply `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute to the field or property.
- Check your enum fields to make sure they are set to a valid value (or are nullable). You may need to add a 0 value to the enum in some cases. (not sure about fine details of this point).

**What to test:**

- [Configure WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) for at least critical errors or exceptions. Be careful to watch filesize if you enable any further traces. This will give some very useful information in many cases.

  Just add this under `<configuration>` in your `web.config` **ON THE SERVER**. Create the `log` directory if it doesn't exist.

```xml
 <system.diagnostics>
     <sources>
       <source name="System.ServiceModel"
               switchValue="Error, Critical"
               propagateActivity="true">
         <listeners>
           <add name="traceListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData= "c:\log\WCF_Errors.svclog" />
         </listeners>
       </source>
     </sources>
   </system.diagnostics>
```

- Make sure the .svc file will actually come up in a browser without error. This will give you some 'first chance' help. For instance if you have a non serializable object you'll get this message below. Note that it clearly tells you what can't be serialized. Make sure you have 'mex' endpoint enabled and bring up the .svc file in your browser.

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true,
>   whose value is:
>       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a
>   WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>        contract: http://tempuri.org/:IOrderPipelineService
>   ----> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException:
>   **Type
>   'RR.MVCServices.PipelineStepResponse'
>   cannot be serialized.** Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.

Comment: +1 Thanks - I was hit by this error, I found your answer, and it turned out the problem was caused by a bitmask enumeration: when you have more than one bit set (and therefore no one enum value that matches) the serialization fails!

Comment: I got a similar problem. The service is fine. One client is working; but the second client is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420314/one-wcf-service-two-clients-one-client-does-not-work

Answer (score 8):

For me, this error message was thrown because my the web.config Service Behavior by default has a low message limit, so when the WCF returned say 200000 bytes and my limit was 64000 bytes the response was truncated and thus you get the "... not meaningful reply". It's meaningful, it's just been truncated and can't be parsed.

I'll paste my web.config change that fixed the issue:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="YourNameSpace.DataServiceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="05:05:00" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500"
       maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The maxItemsInObjectGraph value is the most important!
I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I got a similar problem. The service is fine. One client is working; but the second client is not working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420314/one-wcf-service-two-clients-one-client-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. After spending a mind bending 2 hours on this and trying to find an answer online, I decided to follow the approach to seralize and deserialize the return value/object on the server side using the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer and finally found that I had missed to add EnumMember attribute on one of the Enums.

You may be facing a similar issue.

Here is the code snippet that helped me resolve the issue:

```
      var dataContractSerializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
      byte[] serializedBytes;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mem1 = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(mem1, results);
            serializedBytes = mem1.ToArray();
        }

        MyObject deserializedResult;
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mem2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(serializedBytes))
        {
            deserializedResult = (MyObject)dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(mem2);
        }
```

Comment: This was the quickest option for local debugging, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've just changed the client so it uses a config file instead of code and I get the same error!

Code:

```cs
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new WCFTest.ConsoleClient.ServiceReference1.Service1Client("NetTcpBinding_IService1");    
client.PrintMessage("Hello!");
```

Here is the config file of the client, freshly generated from the Service ... which makes my think that it mightn't be a contract mismatch error

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://servername:9999/TestService1/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="&#xD;&#xA;          " />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://serverName:9990/TestService1/" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="MyUserPrincipalName " />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, probably not - the error message also offers two more possible casuse: "....., a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

Answer (score 0):

If you have two methods with same name and parameters in your WCF it will throw this error